# Can't makes BCP to export data from view to csv

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, bcp

Thanks to **domenicr** now I see, that bcp keys are case sensetive. But another problem appears - bcp asks me about type of the field to write in file each time i run script - is it possible to automate that?

```
Enter the file storage type of field Employee_ID [char]:
```

I need to export data from view to csv file. The easiest way, as it seems to me is BCP. I tried to read MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx for syntax help, but I can't makes bcp to create file cause of error (running bcp from cmd). Thanks in advance for any help with syntacsis.

```
bcp [base_name].[dbo].[all_users_for_ad] out 1.csv -t -c -u mylogin -p mypassword -s mysever


bcp:  unknown option u
usage: bcp {dbtable | query} {in | out | queryout | format} datafile
  [-m maxerrors]            [-f formatfile]          [-e errfile]
  [-F firstrow]             [-L lastrow]             [-b batchsize]
  [-n native type]          [-c character type]      [-w wide character type]
  [-N keep non-text native] [-V file format version] [-q quoted identifier]
  [-C code page specifier]  [-t field terminator]    [-r row terminator]
  [-i inputfile]            [-o outfile]             [-a packetsize]
  [-S server name]          [-U username]            [-P password]
  [-T trusted connection]   [-v version]             [-R regional enable]
  [-k keep null values]     [-E keep identity values]
  [-h "load hints"]         [-x generate xml format file]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BCP command arguments are case sensitive. Should be -T and -S.  For trusted connections, no need to pass user and password.

Use -c to specify character data type or supply a format file with -f argument

Refer to this on how to create a format file. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms191516.aspx

Comment: Well thank you for your comment, it's really true, but I have another problem - each time i run command bcp asks me about file storage type of each field. Is it possible to automate it?